# Algorithm: generate list permutation by preference

Tags: algorithm

I have a function `f` that takes a `list` of items as it's single parameter and returns `true` if the ordering of the items is accepted or `false` if the ordering of the items is not accepted.

There exists at least one or more permutations of list `l` which `f(l)` returns true.

Function `f` is a black box (we don't have it's source code) and the type of the elements held by list `l` are also unknown or generic.

`p` is a permutation of list `l` according to user preferences. The most preferred item has index `0` the least preferred item has index `l.size()-1`
list `p` will always contain all elements of list `l`.

The goal is to find a permutation of `l` let's call it `p_accepted` where `f(p_accepted)` returns true and preference `p` is maximized.

Here's an example

```
given l = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
given p = [c, a, f, b, e, d]

given f([ a, b, c, d, e, f ]) = false
given f([ c, a, f, b, e, d ]) = false
given f([ d, e, b, f, a, c ]) = true
given f([ f, e, d, c, b, a ]) = true
given f([ c, b, f, a, d, e ]) = true
given f([ a, c, f, b, e, d ]) = true
given f([   anything else  ]) = false

the expected output for p_accepted is [c, b, f, a, d, e]
it is accepted because f(p_accepted) returns true and no other permutation of l ranks the item 'c' as high. item 'c' is the most preferred by the user since it has index 0
```

Implementations in pseudo code or any language are accepted.

[EDIT]

**Clarifications**

list `p` will always contain all elements of list `l`

list `l` items can only be compared by identity, i.e.: by reference
so an item in list `p` can be found in list `l` by `l[i] == p[j]`

list `l` items cannot always be compared like in the example where a compare function `c` might determine that `a < b` i.e.: `c('a', 'b') = 1`.

[EDIT 2]
**To understand preferences better**

Imagine Alice and Bob being forced to do 4 tasks together at the same time in order. [task a, task b, task c, task d].
Alice has one preferred order for doing the tasks [a,b,c,d]. Bob has two preferred orders for doing the tasks [a,c,b,d], [a,d,b,c]. If you are Alice, the function `f` would return true only for [a,c,b,d] and [a,d,b,c] which are Bob's preferences, since both like to do task a first `p_accepted` should start with a.

Note that this is an analogy function `f` does not accept permutations based on multiple user's order preference.

Comment: Step 1 is to fully specify how to compare two permutations that are both accepted by f().

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: You say that the *items* in the list have preferences, but your objective function seems to assume that there is another notion of preferences between *permutations* of items. You haven't defined how to extend a ranking of items into a ranking of permutations of those items. There is more than one way to do so.

Comment: In python [itertools.permutations(p)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is a generator that will emit permutations in lex order (relative to the ordering of `p`). If `p` is sorted according to order of decreasing preference and you use lex-order to rank permutations, then the order that the permutations are generated is the order that you seem to want.

Comment: Please see edit 2

Comment: To put it another way, given that f() returns true for exactly two permutations P1 and P2, which one is better, and how do you decide that?

Comment: Given preference permutation P and given that f() returns true for exactly two permutations P1 and P2 you must choose the permutation which can most accurately respect user preference P. Here's an example with numbers: P = [1, 2, 3, 4] 1 is first and preferred before the others, 2 second most preferred and so on; between P1 = [4, 3, 2, 1] and P2 = [3, 4, 2, 1] you must choose P2 since P2 starts with 3 and P1 starts with 4, and since P says that 3 is preferred over 4. I hope that is clarifies things

Comment: So this is lex order? If so -- just generate the permutations in this order until you first get one that is accepted. If `f` is indeed a black-box that you know nothing about, I don't see how you could do anything better than that. This is of course infeasible in the worst case for even moderately long lists, but it is what it is.